# ASP.NET: How to convert schema to Excel xsl

Tags: asp.net, xslt, export-to-excel

I have the following xml schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsd:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0">
    <xs:element name="PercentTimeReport">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="ParamStartDate" type="xs:dateTime" />
                <xs:element name="ParamEndDate" type="xs:dateTime" />
                <xs:element name="ParamQuarterInt" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
                <xs:element name="ParamProjID" nillable="true" />
                <xs:element name="ParamStaffID" nillable="true" />
                <xs:element name="ParamPercentRange" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
                <xs:element name="Items">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Item">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:unsignedShort" />
                                        <xs:element name="EmployeeName" type="xs:string" />
                                        <xs:element name="StaffID" type="xs:unsignedShort" />
                                        <xs:element name="Status" type="xs:string" />
                                        <xs:element name="Date" type="xs:dateTime" />
                                        <xs:element name="Department" type="xs:string" />
                                        <xs:element name="DepartmentCode" type="xs:string" />
                                        <xs:element name="Project" type="xs:string" />
                                        <xs:element name="ProjectID" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
                                        <xs:element name="Hours" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
                                        <xs:element name="HoursPerWeek" type="xs:decimal" />
                                        <xs:element name="PercentTime" type="xs:decimal" />
                                        <xs:element name="ActualContact" type="xs:boolean" />
                                        <xs:element name="Body" type="xs:string" />
                                        <xs:element name="Issue" type="xs:string" />
                                        <xs:element name="Activity" type="xs:string" />
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

and I'd like to generate an excel file that only shows the Items table in an ASP.NET 2.0 Web application.  I really don't understand this [code that I found](http://aspalliance.com/471_Convert_XML_To_an_Excel_Spreadsheet_Using_XSL.all) (see below), or XSLT enough to get the output format that I need.  Does anyone know XSLT, that could tell me how to modify the XSLT below to:

1) Hide the elements other than Items (e.g. ParamStartDate, ParamEndDate, etc.).

2) Output the table with the nested "Items" complex element.

Currently, the xsl below produces each of the elements as column headers, and the Items cell contains all the items on one row.  I essentially need to go one level deeper.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
        xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
        xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
        xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
        xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Workbook>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <Worksheet>
        <xsl:attribute name="ss:Name">
            <xsl:value-of select="local-name(/*/*)"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <Table x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1">
            <Row>
                <xsl:for-each select="*[position() = 1]/*">
                    <Cell>
                        <Data ss:Type="String">
                            <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
                        </Data>
                    </Cell>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Row>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </Table>
    </Worksheet>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/*/*">
    <Row>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Row>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="/*/*/*">
    <Cell>
        <Data ss:Type="String">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </Data>
    </Cell>
</xsl:template>
```

Desired Excel Output (Only show Items complexType as Table):

```
   ID   EmployeeName    StaffID    ....     Issue   Activity
   1     John Smith       231      ....      text     text
   2     Kate Henderson   101      ....      text2    text3
   .                               ....
   .                               ....
   N                               ....
```

Current Output:

```
   ParamStartDate   ParamEndDate   ....    ParamPercentRange   Items
    '01/01/2010'    '04/01/2010'   ....            6           '1John Smith231...texttext....'
```

As always, any help greatly appreciated.

Thank You

P.S. Alejandro, here's the output with your changes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<Worksheet ss:Name="PercentTimeReport">
<Table x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1">
<Row />
</Table>
</Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

Here is a sample of my original output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:user="urn:my-scripts">
    <Worksheet ss:Name="PercentTimeReport">
    <Table x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1">
        <Row>
            <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">ParamStartDate</Data></Cell><Cell><Data ss:Type="String">ParamEndDate</Data></Cell><Cell><Data ss:Type="String">ParamQuarterInt</Data></Cell><Cell><Data ss:Type="String">ParamPercentRange</Data></Cell><Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Items</Data></Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">2010-07-01T00:00:00</Data></Cell><Cell><Data ss:Type="String">2010-09-30T00:00:00</Data></Cell>....</Cell>
        </Row>
    </Table>
    </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

Comment: Please note that you need to indent code by 4 spaces (e.g. by clicking on the corresponding toolbar button). Otherwise, XML code won't be visible.

Comment: Sure, I just need to produce an excel file with a single sheet containing the following columns: ID, EmployeeName, StaffID, Status, Date, Department, DepartmentCode, Project, ProjectID, Hours, TotalHours, HoursPerWeek, PercentTime, ActualContactCount, ActualContactFlag, Body, Issue, Activity.

Comment: Currently it creates a table with columns:  ParamStartDate, ParamEndDate, ..., Items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the template that match `/*` your context (following the schema you've privided) is `PercentTimeReport` root element. It seems that you want to iterate trougth child elements of `PercentTimeReport/Items/Item`.

So change:

```
<xsl:for-each select="*[position() = 1]/*">
```

For:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Items/Item[1]/*">
```

And this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates/>
```

For:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Items/Item"/>
```

And this patterns:

```
<xsl:template match="/*/*">   

<xsl:template match="/*/*/*">
```

For:

```
<xsl:template match="Item">   

<xsl:template match="Item/*">
```

**Edit**: This input (following schema)

```
<PercentTimeReport>
    <ParamStartDate>ParamStartDate</ParamStartDate>
    <ParamEndDate>ParamEndDate</ParamEndDate>
    <ParamQuarterInt>ParamQuarterInt</ParamQuarterInt>
    <ParamProjID>ParamProjID</ParamProjID>
    <ParamStaffID>ParamStaffID</ParamStaffID>
    <ParamPercentRange>ParamPercentRange</ParamPercentRange>
    <Items>
        <Item>
            <ID>ID1</ID>
            <EmployeeName>EmployeeName1</EmployeeName>
            <StaffID>StaffID1</StaffID>
            <Status>Status1</Status>
            <Date>Date1</Date>
            <Department>Department1</Department>
            <DepartmentCode>DepartmentCode1</DepartmentCode>
            <Project>Project1</Project>
            <ProjectID>ProjectID1</ProjectID>
            <Hours>Hours1</Hours>
            <HoursPerWeek>HoursPerWeek1</HoursPerWeek>
            <PercentTime>PercentTime1</PercentTime>
            <ActualContact>ActualContact1</ActualContact>
            <Body>Body1</Body>
            <Issue>Issue1</Issue>
            <Activity>Activity1</Activity>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <ID>ID2</ID>
            <EmployeeName>EmployeeName2</EmployeeName>
            <StaffID>StaffID2</StaffID>
            <Status>Status2</Status>
            <Date>Date2</Date>
            <Department>Department2</Department>
            <DepartmentCode>DepartmentCode2</DepartmentCode>
            <Project>Project2</Project>
            <ProjectID>ProjectID2</ProjectID>
            <Hours>Hours2</Hours>
            <HoursPerWeek>HoursPerWeek2</HoursPerWeek>
            <PercentTime>PercentTime2</PercentTime>
            <ActualContact>ActualContact2</ActualContact>
            <Body>Body2</Body>
            <Issue>Issue2</Issue>
            <Activity>Activity2</Activity>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <ID>ID3</ID>
            <EmployeeName>EmployeeName3</EmployeeName>
            <StaffID>StaffID3</StaffID>
            <Status>Status3</Status>
            <Date>Date3</Date>
            <Department>Department3</Department>
            <DepartmentCode>DepartmentCode3</DepartmentCode>
            <Project>Project3</Project>
            <ProjectID>ProjectID3</ProjectID>
            <Hours>Hours3</Hours>
            <HoursPerWeek>HoursPerWeek3</HoursPerWeek>
            <PercentTime>PercentTime3</PercentTime>
            <ActualContact>ActualContact3</ActualContact>
            <Body>Body3</Body>
            <Issue>Issue3</Issue>
            <Activity>Activity3</Activity>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <ID>ID4</ID>
            <EmployeeName>EmployeeName4</EmployeeName>
            <StaffID>StaffID4</StaffID>
            <Status>Status4</Status>
            <Date>Date4</Date>
            <Department>Department4</Department>
            <DepartmentCode>DepartmentCode4</DepartmentCode>
            <Project>Project4</Project>
            <ProjectID>ProjectID4</ProjectID>
            <Hours>Hours4</Hours>
            <HoursPerWeek>HoursPerWeek4</HoursPerWeek>
            <PercentTime>PercentTime4</PercentTime>
            <ActualContact>ActualContact4</ActualContact>
            <Body>Body4</Body>
            <Issue>Issue4</Issue>
            <Activity>Activity4</Activity>
        </Item>
    </Items>
</PercentTimeReport>
```

With this stylesheet (Yours plus my changes)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Workbook>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </Workbook>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <Worksheet>
            <xsl:attribute name="ss:Name">
                <xsl:value-of select="local-name(/*/*)"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <Table x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1">
                <Row>
                    <xsl:for-each select="Items/Item[1]/*">
                        <Cell>
                            <Data ss:Type="String">
                                <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
                            </Data>
                        </Cell>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </Row>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Items/Item"/>
            </Table>
        </Worksheet>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Item">
        <Row>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </Row>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Item/*">
        <Cell>
            <Data ss:Type="String">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </Data>
        </Cell>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<Workbook xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
    <Worksheet ss:Name="ParamStartDate">
        <Table x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1">
            <Row>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">ID</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">EmployeeName</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">StaffID</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Status</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Date</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Department</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">DepartmentCode</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Project</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">ProjectID</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Hours</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">HoursPerWeek</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">PercentTime</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">ActualContact</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Body</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Issue</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Activity</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">ID1</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">EmployeeName1</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">StaffID1</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Status1</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Date1</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Department1</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">DepartmentCode1</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Project1</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">ProjectID1</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Hours1</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">HoursPerWeek1</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">PercentTime1</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">ActualContact1</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Body1</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Issue1</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Activity1</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">ID2</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">EmployeeName2</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">StaffID2</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Status2</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Date2</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Department2</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">DepartmentCode2</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Project2</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">ProjectID2</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Hours2</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">HoursPerWeek2</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">PercentTime2</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">ActualContact2</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Body2</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Issue2</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Activity2</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">ID3</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">EmployeeName3</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">StaffID3</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Status3</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Date3</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Department3</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">DepartmentCode3</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Project3</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">ProjectID3</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Hours3</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">HoursPerWeek3</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">PercentTime3</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">ActualContact3</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Body3</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Issue3</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Activity3</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">ID4</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">EmployeeName4</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">StaffID4</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Status4</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Date4</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Department4</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">DepartmentCode4</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Project4</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">ProjectID4</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Hours4</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">HoursPerWeek4</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">PercentTime4</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">ActualContact4</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Body4</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Issue4</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Activity4</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
        </Table>
    </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

Comment: Alejandro, I tried your suggestions but now I don't get any output at all.  There are two "<xsl:apply-templates/>" lines, so I tried all combinations.

Comment: @Sephrial: I had to built an input document in order to test... Without adding anything except my suggested changes, it output a proper XML MS-Excel document.

Comment: Thanks Alejandro, I tried your changes, but I still don't recieve any output.  I edited my question to show you the two XLT outputs.  Would it help if I provide a sample of the XML input?  For some reason the Item/Items doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Sephrial: That is because you've posted an incomplete schema. It seems that `PercentTimeReport` it's not your input root element. Just change `match="/*"` for `match="PercentTimeReport"` and it will work. Next time include complete input sample or complete schema, please.

Comment: @Sephrial: We are not understanding each other. Post your input sample.